# How do I select a particular ROW in a single column CSV file containing a particular "substring" and add to a new list with python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column CSV file with a large number of rows. How do I extract a row containing a particular "substring" and then add the row to a new list?

Regards

Prabhat

Comment: please include a sample of the data that you're working with in order for us to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this gets you moving towards a solution...

Input list (need to return all rows with the letters a and t together ('at')...

```
     Col1
0        the
1        cat
2        sat
3         on
4        the
5        mat
6        for
7          a
8       very
9       long
10      time
11        at
12  Batman’s
13     house
```

Code...

```
my_substring = 'at'
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.contains(my_substring, na=False)
df = df[df.Col2]
del df['Col2']
df
```

Output...

```
 Col1
1        cat
2        sat
5        mat
11        at
12  Batman’s
```